# Derivative with awkward vec term

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have an expression that I need to find the derivative of, but I can't work out how to derive it as the variable I am wanting the gradient with respect to is inside a vec operator. Such that:

$tr(\mathbf{A}vec(\mathbf{S}\mathbf{X})vec(\mathbf{S}\mathbf{X})^T\mathbf{A}^T)$

$\mathbf{A} \text{ and } \mathbf{X}$ are known matrices, and I want the derivative of this expression with respect to $\mathbf{S}$.

How does one go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 v &= {\rm vec}(SX) = {\rm vec}(ISX) \cr
   &= (X^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(S) = (X^T\otimes I)\,\sigma \cr\cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of the Frobenius Product, then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= Av:Av \cr\cr
df &= 2\,Av:Adv \cr
   &= 2\,A^TAv:dv \cr
   &= 2\,A^TAv:(X^T\otimes I)\,d\sigma \cr
   &= 2\,(X\otimes I)\,A^TAv:d\sigma \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\sigma} &= 2\,(X\otimes I)\,A^TAv \cr\cr
}$$
To recover the gradient wrt the matrix $S$, "matricize" the vector result by unstacking the columns
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial S} &= {\rm Mat}\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\sigma}\Big) \cr
}$$
where $${\rm Mat}\big(\sigma\big)={\rm Mat}\big({\rm vec}(S)\big)=S$$